# Best practice selecting database for mobile app

Tags: android, ios, database, mobile

So, I am fairly new to mobile app developing.  Are currently making project documents for a mobile app, and I want some input on what database solution I should use.

1) mobile app -> online only -> talking to a database

2) I Have several webservers up and running (mysql mostly), possible to use?

So my question is simple :) What solution should I use for my mobile app database. 
- Setup a mysql database on a server?
- Use some kind of cloud based solution?
- Any API considurations?

- need to be "best practice" for both android and ios.

Any and all suggestions is much appreciated! Thanks all! You are AWESOME!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom - If you need data to be available offline without internet connectivity then you should you SQLITE database which comes as part of android/ios.

If your app saves the data on server which in turn is used by other portal or other devices (sharing) then consider storing data via web/server and mysql database.

So really it depends on the usage and sharing requirements. Storing data locally has much benefit because it is faster, no network required, data always available, and not using network also increases battery life..

Comment: Thanks for input. Requirements are people sharing "data" with each other. Will not go into spesifics, but basicly, person 1 open app, and see person 2, 3, 4 data. So register, and share data. Any input on best practice to save/retreive data from mysql? Build an API?

Comment: In that case - you need server component too. Server should expose webservice. Webservice could be of REST/JSON type which are best suited for phones. To give best user experience, you should sync data with server and store locally in SQLITE (in iOS you use core data to use sqlite).

Comment: So mysql (innodb) is a good solution? No need for any "spesific" database solution for mobile apps? Suggestion on what approach for REST on server side? anything out there to take a look at?

Comment: If you expect your app to always fetch data from server and don't want to store data locally, yes no specific database for mobile app. Again you only have 1 choice, which is default SQLite in ios and android both. To get data from server, you call web service. Its upto server which database they want to use. Whether they use oracle or mysql, data is exposed via web service and mobile app doesn't get impacted by any database used on server side.

Answer (score 5):

Tom,

The most common solution for this problem is:

1) Your application get data via a webservice in your server. You can use Soap solution based on XML communication, or simple REST access (simple http request in GET or POST method) and use your own choice: XML or JSON.
Today, there is a lot of solution based on REST GET/POST with JSON file communication.

2) After, if you want that your application can turn in offline mode or just be more reactive, you can store old loaded data by webservice in local database.
For this, in Android you can use direct access to sqlite database, and in iOs, you can use the CoreData api.

Hope it help you.

Fabecc.